# How to display image from device library in React Native mobile app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, mobile-application

I am trying to implement a functionality where it allows the user to tap the "Add Photo" component and their device photo library pops up to add/choose an image to display. However, I am testing this and although my console.log(result) seems to be working & outputting fine it is not displaying the image, the component stays the same as I have upon startup (check image attached). Note, I am using expo with IOS simulator, I also wanted to ask if implemented correctly, is it maybe a simulation environment causing this to not display?

[image: screen after choosing an image]

User Profile.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';

const Profile = ({ route }) => {
  const user = route.params.user.user;
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(user.username);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(user.password);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user.email);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState(null);
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [joinedDate, setJoinedDate] = useState(null);
  const deviceLanguage = Localization.locale;

  const pickImage = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      });
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setProfileImage(result.uri);
        console.log('Image picker result:', result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error picking image', error);
    }
  };  

  const handleSaveChanges = () => {
    console.log('Updated Data:');
    console.log('User Name:', username);
    console.log('Password:', password)
    console.log('Email:', email);
    console.log('Phone Number:', phoneNumber);
    console.log('Image:', profileImage);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work.');
        }
      }
    })();
    
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const formattedDate = currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    setJoinedDate(formattedDate);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>
          <View style={styles.profileImageContainer}>
            {profileImage ? (
              <Image source={{ uri: profileImage }} style={styles.profileImage} />
            ) : (
              <Text style={styles.addPhotoText}>Add Photo</Text>
            )}
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Profile Setting</Text>
          <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Username:</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={username}
              onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
              placeholderTextColor="gray"
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Password:</Text>
            <View style={styles.passwordInput}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.passInput}
                placeholder="Password"
                onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                value={password}
                secureTextEntry={!showPassword} 
                placeholderTextColor="gray"
              />
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)} style={styles.eyeIcon}>
                <Icon
                  name={showPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-slash'}
                  size={20}
                  color="gray"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Email:</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={email}
              onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
              placeholderTextColor="gray"
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Phone Number:</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={(text) => setPhoneNumber(text)}
              value={phoneNumber}
              placeholderTextColor="gray"
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.fieldLabel}>Joined Date:</TextInput>
            <TextInput style={styles.input}>{joinedDate}</TextInput>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.fieldLabel}>Device Language:</TextInput>
            <TextInput style={styles.input}>{deviceLanguage}</TextInput>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.saveButton} onPress={handleSaveChanges}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save Changes</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  profileImageContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    borderRadius: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  profileImage: {
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    borderRadius: 60,
  },
  addPhotoText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  infoContainer: {
    width: '80%',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  passwordInput: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  passInput: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
  },
  eyeIcon: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  labelText: {
    color: 'gray',
    marginTop: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  dateOfBirthText: {
    color: 'black',
    marginTop: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  inputHalf: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    flex: 1,
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  inputThird: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    flex: 1,
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  addressRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  saveButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#5CB85C',
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  fieldContainer: {
    marginBottom: 0,
  },
  fieldLabel: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 8,
    color: 'gray',
  },
});
export default Profile;
```

I tried debugging and this is the output for console.log(result) on line 28:

```
Image picker result: Object {
  "assets": Array [
    Object {
      "assetId": "99D53A1F-FEEF-40E1-8BB3-7DD55A43C8B7/L0/001",
      "base64": null,
      "duration": null,
      "exif": null,
      "fileName": "IMG_0004.JPG",
      "fileSize": 2321139,
      "height": 1668,
      "type": "image",
      "uri": "file:///Users/besabunjaku/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3DC7595-6F7F-44A4-874E-B96D527973B3/data/Containers/Data/Application/83A2BCEE-AB17-4A5C-AC82-012BC9617172/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FHalaFinds-9c96a55d-e687-44f0-afcb-48668cf9406a/ImagePicker/02AB4D6E-AFFA-4E06-9B22-5CA87261A85A.jpg",
      "width": 1668,
    },
  ],
  "canceled": false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `result` contains the `Array` named `assets`, but you treat it as the `Object`, hence it's cause problem, to fix it, just use:

```
setProfileImage(result.assets[0].uri);
```

Comment: If I add the index in I get this error,
Error picking image [TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined]